# Parsing multiple .tsv with Pandas - efficient indexing and parsing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am parsing many hundreds of .tsv files from different directories. Each file has only 2 columns, and the idea is to use the index in one column for concatenation later on.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({ 'A':['name1.0', 'name2.0', 'name3.0'], 'B':[4., 3., 2.]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({ 'A':['name1.0', 'name3.0', 'name4.0', 'name5.3'], 'B':[3., 4., 5., 0.]})
```

The problems:

1. The column to serve as index must be parsed;
2. Files may have different numbers of rows.

What is an efficient way of doing this in python/pandas?

Using `df1` and `df2` above, the idea is then to concatenate the dataframes based on the transformed indices. For instance:

```
df1.index=[re.sub('\..+$','',i) for i in df1.loc[:,'A']]
df2.index=[re.sub('\..+$','',i) for i in df2.loc[:,'A']]
out=pd.concat([df1.loc[:,'B'],df2.loc[:,'B']],axis=1)
out
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? THank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here one way that allow you to load every at once and do a axis=0 concat:

Load your files with an extra column I called `fileid` in that exemple that allow you to identify rows coming from a given file. You should be able to do that in your loading loop

```
df1
Out[189]: 
         A    B  fileid
0  name1.0  4.0       1
1  name2.0  3.0       1
2  name3.0  2.0       1

df2
Out[190]: 
         A    B  fileid
0  name1.0  3.0       2
1  name3.0  4.0       2
2  name4.0  5.0       2
3  name5.3  0.0       2
```

Do a one time clean up on your column `A`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

df.A = df.A.str.split('.', n=1, expand=True)[0]

df
Out[183]: 
       A    B  fileid
0  name1  4.0       1
1  name2  3.0       1
2  name3  2.0       1
0  name1  3.0       2
1  name3  4.0       2
2  name4  5.0       2
3  name5  0.0       2
```

Pivot it. Columns are naturally identified by the file they come from with the naming convention used in `fileid`:

```
df.pivot('A', 'fileid', 'B')
Out[192]: 
fileid    1    2
A               
name1   4.0  3.0
name2   3.0  NaN
name3   2.0  4.0
name4   NaN  5.0
name5   NaN  0.0
```

For a larger audience, I find this approach advantageous because when we deal with way more files or when we want to parallelize the calculation, this approach fits well with [`dask`](http://dask.pydata.org): you apply the [simple recipe here](https://gist.github.com/mrocklin/e7b7b3a65f2835cda813096332ec73ca) to get dask loading yourfile in parallel *and* adding the `fileid`column at the same time. And now you can compute your entire resulting dataframe in parallel "for free" (like 5 more lines of code, `import dask` statement included...)

Comment: Wow I didn't think it would be so elegant. Thank you!

Comment: I am having problems running my code due to memory issues, likely because of the file size and number of files. I suppose parallelizing it doesn't solve my problem. How would you do it? My approach now is to try and split inputs and outputs to half, and then processing the new tables again.